# ETL - OLAP & OLTP - Maintain reporting and transnational Database in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, database-administration, sql-server-2014-express

My requirement is to maintain two database in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio (one for transaction and another for reporting) for single application developed in EF 7 and MVC 6.

My question is

1. what are the technologies I can implement for my requirement?
2. How to Implement and maintain two database?

I did some R&D regarding the requirement [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103887/moving-transaction-data-to-another-database-for-reporting-purpose) but I cannot find the actual solution. Solution I find from R&D is Mirroring, synchronisation and CDT. I am not been able to figure out which technology to use for data replication.

I want to feed data in reporting db at the time of transaction in transaction db and I may be allowed for updating the reporting db.

Comment: "Teach me using databases" - too broad. "Teach me about data marts, and ETL" - too broad. "Tell me what technologies to use" - off topic.

Comment: Agree with @TomTom, this is rather too broad for this platform. I have voted to put on hold.

Answer (score 0):

Basically SQL Server 2014 is the first in-memory database on SQL Server data platform.
This means, the transactional (OLTP) and reporting (OLAP) capabilities are merged and covered by SQL Server 2014. You can check how to [create in-memory database on SQL Server 2014](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2014/create-in-memory-database-in-sql-server-2014.aspx).
Actually I'm not sure how successful is this approach but SAP HANA is being marketed with this saying.
The column-store indexing and compression ratios with decreasing prizes of memory brought in-memory databases enhancements with Sybase, SQL Server, Hana and now Oracle